# How to highlight/select Clicked Character in Input Text Box?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

In Visual Studio, C#, WPF, I have an input textbox with time format 00:00:00.000. Hours:Minutes:Seconds.Milliseconds.

[image]

When a 0 is clicked, it places the I-cursor next to it like normal. You must backspace the 0 and type the number you want. Or you can drag and highlight it manually.

I'm trying to simplify this process. How can I make it to where when you click a 0, it highlights just that one character, and when you type it overwrites it?

And is it possible to disable the colon and period from being selected, so they are not removed?

```
<TextBox x:Name="cutStart" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" Margin="415,129,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="00:00:00.000" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" IsEnabled="True" />
```

Comment: What UI framework are you using? There is no code posted, so I can't even guess.

Comment: @CodyGray WPF, I have updated question with code.

Comment: I'm trying to solve this exact problem right now. My current idea is to create many text boxes with MaxLength=1 in a single control and use events to highlight when an individual text box is selected.